# RPM overwrite file if it was not modified

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have an RPM and the **SPEC file**. My application has a file (myfile.txt), which is installed in /mypath. So, when my RPM is installed we have /mypath/myfile.txt in the server.

The file `/mypath/myfile.txt` contains a single word: hello

**What I want to achieve is**: From a fresh installation or an upgrade, install myfile.txt only if the content did not change.

Use cases:

- If `/mypath/myfile.txt` does not exist, install it.
- If `/mypath/myfile.txt` exists and it keeps the original value "hello", overwrite it.
- If `/mypath/myfile.txt` exists and the content changed to "whatever", `/mypath/myfile.txt` should not be overwritten when the application is upgraded.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The usage you describe is almost what rpm does with a %config file.

The one difference is that rpm renames the old modified file with a .rpmold suffix.

If you also add %noreplace, then the new file will be written with a .rpmnew suffix and the original file is left in place.

Comment: Yes, with %noreplace I can avoid cases 1 and 2, but not 3 because I have a condition

Comment: When the file is marked as %config(noreplace) then rpm will not replace it when it has been modified. It will install the new file as myfile.txt.rpmnew and the original one will be intact

Answer (score 0):

As msuchy said, you need %config(noreplace)

Source : [https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm_config.html](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejw35/docs/rpm_config.html)